# Unable to start mainnet node docker container

Tags: node, docker

When starting the node directly from the docker image, I get this error:

```
| Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z-betanet.
   | Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z-betanet.
   | Updating the node configuration...
   | tezos-node: Error:
   |               Ezjsonm.Parse_error(870828711, "JSON.of_buffer expected JSON
   |             text (JSON value)")
```

Container SHA is `d272059bf474018d0c39f5a6e60634a95f0c44aa`

No idea how to debug this.. This is a direct deployment from the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `config.json` has been corrupted.
You can try deleting it or restoring it from a backup if you have one.